# How to set calendar view in list view web part using CSOM in share point 2013

Tags: web-part, office-365, list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a calendar type of list in which I have set up overlays.

When manually I add the same calendar list in the list view web part, it shows me  all the events and the overlays in the web part.

I want to have the same using CSOM in O365.

Please suggest .